# fetch the record which has exactly 3 days left for expiry

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the record which has exactly 3 days left for expire.I want to select the date which is exactly 3 days left from current date.my table name is'member' I want to calculate using the field 'time'.

```
$chk="SELECT * FROM member WHERE TIME > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 2 DAY ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURDATE()`, `DATE()` and `DATE_ADD()` functions.

```
     $chk="SELECT * FROM member 
WHERE expiry_date_field = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_ADD`

Supposing time is the field that has date entries

```
 SELECT * FROM member  WHERE `TIME` =  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

this will get the records where date is future date 3 days from now

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date_SUB(), Now() function to achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM member 
WHERE expiry_date_field
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 3 DAY ) AND NOW( );
```

Also just a advice, it is not a good practice to use SELECT * . Even you need all the columns then also specify column names . The concept behind this is in the future your member table can have additional columns which is not needed for this query result. But if you use select * mysql will also select them unnecessarily.